# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in MyApp.DLL

The C# codes are following. The error Pointer was indicating on LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri) "this is the next statement that will be executed".

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private async void SetBackground1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync() == LockScreenRequestResult.Granted)
        {
            var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You said no, so I can't update your background.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems that `ms-appx:///Assets/1.jpg` doesn't exist. Are you sure you can access this file?

Comment: MAke sure that the path is correct.

Comment: Have you set image's BuildAction property to Content?

Comment: System.Windows.ApplicationUnhandledException is occurred when I changed the path. Please tell me how exactly the path is taken.

Comment: I recall experiencing something similar while working on one of my recent app updates.  I know this sounds _crazy_, but if you use a `try` / `catch` to ignore the exception, does the lock screen image still get set properly (i.e., maybe it's not **your** file that can't be found)?

Answer (score 2):

Save your image to Isolated Storage instead of project folder. Then retrieve the image from isolated storage whenever you want like this,

```
  var lockimageuri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///Local/" + "lockimage0.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
  LockScreen.SetImageUri(lockimageuri);
```

Here locimage0.jpg is the image that present in the isolated storage.

Here is the code to save your image into Isolated storage.

```
   using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
   {
          string filePath = "lockimage0.jpg";
          if (store.FileExists(filePath))
          {
                store.DeleteFile(filePath);
          }
          IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = store.CreateFile(filePath);
          wbm.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wbm.PixelWidth, wbm.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
          fileStream.Close();
     }
```

Also You can use this method to read your local image from project folder.

```
 private WriteableBitmap ReadLocalImage(string Uri)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri(Uri, UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
        return wb;

    }
```

This is how I implemented custom lock screen in my application.

Also make sure that you updated the Manifest file

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Background" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

I also tried with image in local project folder, That also working fine for me. Here is the code I tried.

```
private async void SetLockScreen()
{
           //Check to see if the app is currently the lock screen provider
           if (!LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
           {
                //Request to be lock screen provider
                await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
           }

           //Check to see if the app is currently the lock screen provider
           if (LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication)
           {
                //Set the image to the lock screen image
                Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/lockscreen.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
               LockScreen.SetImageUri(imageUri);
           }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure that the image exists in the specified location, and it's `Build Action` property is set to `Content`:

[image]

Comment: I've checked the image exists in specified location and  it's Build Action property is set to Content.

Comment: I copy&pasted your code, and it works for me with this configuration.

Comment: So the error is not due to codes, then why is the exception shown ?

Comment: I don't know. If you try to reproduce the error in a new project, does it happen too?

Comment: I have created my project three times, but all of these have the same exception.

Comment: Could you upload the project somewhere, so the I could get and try it? (e.g. SkyDrive).